# Fold Right operator in Scala unexpected behavior

Tags: scala, syntax

Why does

```
(1 to 5).:\ (0)(_ + _)
```

work, whereas

```
(1 to 5) :\ (0)(_ + _)
```

gives me an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case, you are using the binary operator `:\` like a method where `0` is the only parameter. This returns a curried function into which you pass the lambda `_+_`, just as you intended.

The second case, where you are using `:\` as an infix operator, fails because of operator precedence. Scala tries to evaluate `(0)(_+_)` first, giving the error `Int(0) does not take parameters` because `(0)` is not a function.

In order to use syntax like the second version you will need to add some parens:

```
scala> ((1 to 5) :\ 0)(_+_)
res1: Int = 15
```

Just as an aside, every operator is a method in Scala and can be used like one:

```
scala> 2.+(3)
res2: Int = 5
```

Comment: Actually every operator IS a method in scala.